# Understanding implications of sudo -u -H

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, sudo

I'm trying to install gitlab from [this guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-9-stable/doc/install/installation.md) on Ubuntu 14.04 Server. It is also worth mentioning that I'm behind a http proxy. I'm having problems with this line in particular:

`sudo -u git -H git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git -b 6-9-stable gitlab`

I have `hhtp_proxy` environmental variable set but according to some reading about that I've done you need to set proxy details for git independently by issuing the following command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://some.proxy.com:8080
```

So with that set I wanted to try and understand the `sudo -u <user> -H <command>` syntax.

From reading the sudo man page for the -u -H flags, -u will mean the command will be executed as the git user. -H sets the HOME environment variable to the homedir of the target user. That all makes sense since the git user is supposed to own the gitlab service.

`git clone <url to repo> -b 6-9-stable gitlab` will pull down the repository at the specified url, assign it to a new branch called 6-9-stable and place all the contents of the repo in the gitlab directory.

The problem is when I run:

```
`sudo -u git -H git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git -b 6-9-stable gitlab
```

The connection fails with the following output:

```
Cloning into 'gitlab'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

I've also tried dropping the *s* in https since I know port 443 is synonymous with SSL/TLS  but I still get the same output ... which I don't really understand.

However If I just run:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git -b 6-9-stable gitlab
```

The repo downloads fine. Now I know I could just move it to ~/git and perform the appropriate chmod / chown but I'd really like to understand why I am seeing this behaviour and how to get the desired outcome using `sudo -u <user> -H <command>` syntax.

Many Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Maybe the proxy setting is user specific. Try to set the http.proxy via sudo as well, then try the sudo command again, see if that works.

Comment: yup I knew it would be something simple I was overlooking so sudo -u git -H git config --global ... etc works ... want to write up a proper answer so I can award you the answer ?

Comment: To reflect I feel the semantics of --global are a bit off if settings applied with that flag aren't truly reflected globally across the system ... ah well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the command `git config --global http.proxy http://some.proxy.com:8080` only works on a per-user base.

If you use your `git clone` call with user *git*, you have to use your `git config` call with the user *git* as well.